# Images VERY LARGE when downloading

Tags: python, image

I'm trying to download some pictures from a website. When I download them with the browser they are much smaller than the one, downloaded with my code.They have the same resolution as the one downloaded with my code, but the difference between the filesizes is very large!

```
def download(url, pathname):
    """
    Downloads a file given an URL and puts it in the folder `pathname`
    """
    # if path doesn't exist, make that path dir
    if not os.path.isdir(pathname):
        os.makedirs(pathname)
    # download the body of response by chunk, not immediately
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

    # get the total file size
    file_size = int(response.headers.get("Content-Length", 0))

    # get the file name
    filename = os.path.join(pathname, url.split("/")[-1])


        # progress bar, changing the unit to bytes instead of iteration (default by tqdm)
    progress = tqdm(response.iter_content(1024), f"Downloading {filename}", total=file_size, unit="B", unit_scale=True,
                        unit_divisor=1024, disable=True)

    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        for data in progress.iterable:
            # write data read to the file
            f.write(requests.get(url).content)
            # update the progress bar manually
            progress.update(len(data))
```

Example: https://wallpaper-mania.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/High_resolution_wallpaper_background_ID_77700030695.jpg

- Browser: About 222 KB
- Code: 48,4 MB

How does this difference come about? How can I improve the code to download images in way, they are smaller?

Comment: Should `f.write(requests.get(url).content)` be `f.write(data)`? It looks like you're re-downloading the entire file for every 1024 byte chunk, so you're getting 222 copies of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f.write(requests.get(url).content)
```

It looks like you're re-downloading the entire file for every 1024 byte chunk, so you're getting 222 copies of the image. Make that:

```
f.write(data)
```